# unexpected token "pipeless-text" error with markdown

Tags: markdown

I have the following markdown and have installed markdown via npm.

```
#content

:markdown

    #Websites

    1. [Wikipedia] (http://www.Wikipedia.org/)
```

When I access the site I receive the following error

```
unexpected token "pipeless-text"
```

Any ideas as to what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting rid of the extra line below `:markdown` might help.

```
#content

:markdown
    #Websites

    1. [Wikipedia] (http://www.Wikipedia.org/)
```